# Interesting questions for inverse parabolic problems

Tags: reference-request, oc.optimization-and-control, parabolic-pde, inverse-problems, regularization

I'm looking for some interesting questions and maybe open problems in inverse problems theory, especially in the framework of **parabolic PDEs** (basically the heat equation). As key words here we can cite for instance:

1) Carleman estimate (to prove uniqueness and stability results).

2) Regularization theory (to regularize ill-posedness).

If someone knows any interesting questions or open problems it would be helpful to list it here. Any recommendation of surveys papers is welcome.

Comment: http://www.math.purdue.edu/~eremenko/dvi/heatproblem.pdf

Comment: @Alexandre Eremenko interesting! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Inverse Problems for Partial Differential Equations](https://books.google.nl/books?id=K_aNMWE5O38C) (third edition, 2017) by Victor Isakov concludes each chapter with a collection of open research problems. Chapter 9 is specifically devoted to inverse parabolic problems. I reproduce one of the "open problems" from that chapter:

[image]